# Return based on values selected

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-order-by, case

*I really don't know how to phrase the title correctly, so please excuse me if the title is confusing.*

Here's the scenario I am facing:
I have a table...assuming it contains the follow rows.

```
Name  | Value
----- | ----
John  | 1
Mary  | 2
Jack  | 3
Jim   | 4
```

Here's the PL/SQL requirement:

1. If John exists, return John and his value.
2. If John does not exist, but Mary does, return Mary and her value.
3. If neither John nor Mary exist, return either Jack or Jim whichever
   has the higher value.

I was able to use cursor to traverse the table and test each row, but am wondering if there are other more efficient way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a cursor and a loop. You can do this in a single query, using a conditional sort and a `fetch` clause:

```
select *
from mytable
order by 
    case name when 'John' then 1 when 'Mary' then 2 else 3 end, 
    value desc
fetch first row only
```

Or if you are a pre-12c version of Oracle, where the `fetch` clause is not available:

```
select name, value
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(order by 
            case name when 'John' then 1 when 'Mary' then 2 else 3 end, 
            value desc
        ) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: @JohnnyWu: this does what you ask for. Here is a db fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1ba0fc3058ec0fb3b87f16e986d22bbc

Comment: @GMB...my apology...this actually works!  brilliant!  would you mind explaining the inner select?  thanks!